# Most efficient way to count amount of alphanumeric words within a string using C++

Tags: c++

Let a word be defined as any string of consecutive alphanumerics. Words are parsed by any non alphanumeric. Ex.

"Hi my 1st name@is@Kevin :)"

output: 6

I know would could simply go through the string using a for loop but what would be the most efficient way to return the right output using the full extent of the c++ 11 library?

My current iteration:

```
int findWords(string line) {
    regex AN("[[:alnum:]]");
    int count = 0;
    bool state = false;
    for (char c : line) {
        string s(1, c);
        bool match = regex_match(s, AN);

        if (match && !state) {
            state = true;
        }
        else if (!match && state) {
            count++;
            state = false;
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }

    }

    if (state == true) { //won't count last word otherwise
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Unless you manage to change some fundamental laws of physics of this universe, you must "simply go through the string using a for loop", or an equivalent process. And a rose by any other name...

Comment: What makes you think you can avoid iterating through the string? And more importantly what have you tried - profiled and found?

Comment: C++ is really good at iterating over strings.  Thats almost certainly gonna be fastest.  Incidentally, is there really a sequence of 6 alphanumerics in that string?

Comment: Take a look in the algorithms header. You can delegate the loop to the standard library but not avoid it/them altogether.

Comment: You generally look for a faster way to do something once you have determined, that your solution isn't fast enough. Have you?

Comment: Clarification: Sorry I didn't mean avoid iterating through the string altogether, just a more graceful way to approach it. Hope the edits help.

Comment: using a regex seems a little bit heavy weight to me; a test with `isalpha()` should work, too, and avoids building temporary string objects.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no specific function in c++ library that counts words consisting solely of alphanumerics. For example, an `istream::iterator` in conjunction with `distance` would count "words" separated by white spaces, but would count `he is aged 45` as 4 words. One could also think of `strtok` or regular expressions, but the overhead would be much (much) more than a simple loop. So try, for example, the following. Unless you use this method billion times during program execution, it should perform good enough. If not, let me know :-).
Here you go:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    string line = "Hi my 1st name@is@Kevin :)";

    bool isInAlphaMode = false;
    int count = 0;
    const char* str = line.c_str();
    while (char c = *str) {
        if (isalpha(c) && !isInAlphaMode) {
            count++;
            isInAlphaMode = true;
        }
        else if (!isalpha(c) && isInAlphaMode) {
            isInAlphaMode = false;
        }
        str++;
    }

    printf("string '%s' contains %d words", line.c_str(), count);
    // output: string 'Hi my 1st name@is@Kevin :)' contains 6 words
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I used isalnum() instead of isalpha() or regex. "Words" like twenty1st would've counted for 2 words instead of the needed 1. But other than that, everything works.